# Reatividade em evento

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estou com um problema em mudar o estado de renderização de um elemento com o vue js. O mesmo foi gerado com um `for`. O objetivo é fazer com que o `box-body` do mini panel seja exibido ao clicar em `button`. porém o estado `v-if` é alterado somente quando eu disparo outro evento click em outro elemento aí ele renderiza o html.

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
           <div class="row">
               <div v-for="(beach, index) in markers" :key="index" class="col-md-3 mx-0 px-1 my-1">
                       <div class="box box-default box-solid">
                           <div class="box-header with-border">
                               <h3 class="box-title">{{beach.label}}</h3>
                               <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                   <button type="button" @click="beach.show =! beach.show;" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                                   </button>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                           <div v-if="beach.show">
                               <div class="box-body">
                                    <h5>{{beach.infoText}}</h5>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Iniciei um novo projeto com o `vue-create` e copiei o seu código. Aparentemente está funcionando tudo ok, se entendi corretamente.

Teste com o código abaixo. Caso esteja ocorrendo problemas, me envie o seu `<script>` e o problema que está ocorrendo que edito a mensagem.

```
    <template>
      <div class="col-lg-9">
          <div class="row">
             <div v-for="(beach, index) in markers" :key="index" class="col-md-3 mx-0 px-1 my-1">
                 <div class="box box-default box-solid">
                     <div class="box-header with-border">
                         <h3 class="box-title">{{beach.label}}</h3>
                         <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                             <button type="button" @click="beach.show = !beach.show;" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                               Teste
                             </button>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div v-if="beach.show">
                         <div class="box-body">
                              <h5>{{beach.infoText}}</h5>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      name: 'HelloWorld',
      data () {
        return {
          markers: [
            {
              infoText: 'Info Test',
              show: false,
              label: 'Label Test'
            },
            {
              infoText: 'Info Test 2',
              show: false,
              label: 'Label Test 2'
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      props: {
        msg: String
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Resolvi o problema atribuindo um valor a minha props markers dentro de data return. Assim funcionou. Esqueci de mencionar que estava obtendo os dados de uma props. Se souber porque isso ocorre ficarei grato em ver a edição.

Comment: Ah sim, tem como mandar a parte do <script> e o array que você está passando por props por favor? Pra eu conseguir testar certinho, pois eu montei o array ali no que eu imaginava que estava acontecendo, realmente não mexi em muita coisa não.